# trying to make login recognize admin

Tags: php, mysql, web

```
<?php
ob_start();
include 'connection.php';

$user_id = $_POST ['user_id'];
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];


$query = "SELECT *  FROM Register WHERE username= '$username' AND  Password =           '$password' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in the query: $query. " .     mysqli_error());

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
echo '' . $username . '';
header('location:Login.php');

} else {
$_SESSION['error'] = 'User not recognised';
echo 'user not recognised';
header('location:Login.php');

}

if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$_SESSION['user_id'] == 1;
header('Location: AdminPage.php'); <------------

} else {
header('Location: ProtectedPage.php');
}
?>
```

where the arrow is pointing is my issue my website just sends me to the protected page rather than the Admin page, anyone care to help me with this issue.

Comment: Lovely [SQL injection attack](http://bobby-tables.com) vulnerability there. Plus both of yoru first if() code paths redirect you back to the login page, no matter WHAT comes out of the query. You also try to fetch the SAME row of data again, which will fail since it was already fetched.

Answer (score 1):

The program flow continues use `exit()`

```
header('Location: AdminPage.php'); <------------
exit();
} else {
```

Comment: just tried that it still chucks me onto the protected page instead of admin

Comment: You also have session with comparison operator.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean

```
if($_SESSION['user_id'] == 1) {
    header('Location: AdminPage.php');
}
```

Double equals (`==`) is a comparison operator, not an assignment operator.

Comment: changed it still issue is occuring

Comment: I'm just not quite clear on what this is trying to accomplish.  Do you want to set the session user_id to 1, or check if it is 1?

Answer (score 0):

You are doing the check on the assignation of the mysqli assoc into the `$row` variable.

To check for a user, use the `mysqli_num_rows()` and check if it's bigger than 1. If so, that means there is a user with the credentials provided.

Something like this:

```
$nbRow = mysqli_num_rows($result);
if($nbRow > 0){
    //User exist
}else{
    //User doesn't exist
}
```

It should also be faster since you don't return the entire row.

Comment: where do i enter this into? sorry im a bit of a noob with coding

Comment: instead of doing your `if()` check on the assiocation of the `$row` Do it outside the if() and check the variable $row instead.. you could just do the following : `$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)` and `if($row){...`  you only need to do the fetch assoc one time, and use the row for each of your checks

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape your `$_POST` variables before putting them into your query, or use a prepared statement.

`$query = $connection->real_escape_string($query);`

Also, your `if` statements look a little wacky.

`if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` should probably be

`if ($row == mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` and

`$_SESSION['user_id'] == 1;` should be `$_SESSION['user_id'] = 1;`

Edit: You've also got two `if` statements checking for the same thing, but doing different tasks.  You can't execute `if ($row == mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {` twice and expect two different results.

If you have a user_id in your MySQL table then your php should look like this:

```
if ($result = mysqli_query($connection, $query)){ 
    if ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
      $_SESSION['username'] = $row['username'];
      $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
    }
    if ($_SESSION['user_id'] == 1){
      header('Location: AdminPage.php');
    }
    else { header('Location: ProtectedPage.php'); }

    }
    else { 
      echo 'user not recognised';
      header('location:Login.php');
    }
```

Something like that...it's not tested.

Answer (score 0):

I will let the others point out that the logic you are using right now is wrong, but even when you have fixed these issues I want to emphasize that this:

```
$query = "SELECT *  FROM Register WHERE username= '$username' AND  Password =           '$password' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connection, $query) or exit("Error in the query: $query. " .     mysqli_error());
```

... is VERY dangerous. You should use a library that properly escapes queries like PDO Mysql (http://www.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.php), or at least escape your user input. Right now your query is vulnerable to MySQL injection attacks. Your query also shows that passwords are neither encrypted nor hashes, something that you should look at and implement, or rely on libraries or packages that might do it for you. I personally would not start development on an authentication system when composer allows you to install so many great ones that already implement best practices like these.

Comment: i know my code has issues but it all works apart from this issue so rather than pick apart my code can you just help me solve this issue

Comment: That's not a good approach, @user3542378.  Users here take security very seriously, and in order to learn you should seriously consider the problems associated with SQL injections.